# Is CyberGrasp ROS interface available?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, all.

It appears that ROS I/F for Cyberglove is available.
(http://www.ros.org/wiki/cyberglove)
This I/F will be very helpful for those who use Linux system to integrate the CyberGlove series.

**I am wondering if ROS also supports for I/F for CyberGrasp system**.
CyberGrasp system consists of CyberGlove, exoskeleton module, and Force Controller Unit(FCU).
The FCU communicates with external user PC through ethernet.
This is somewhat different from CyberGlove which uses serial port or USB.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9691/is-cybergrasp-ros-interface-available?/) by [Jiyoung Kim](https://answers.ros.org/users/409/jiyoung-kim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It does not look like there is an implementation of CyberGrasp at the moment.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0